# Bootstrap how to get rid of margin in a alert component

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I've a lot of trouble to get rid of margin

in an alert box using bootstrap alert component

and I dont really understand why !

https://codepen.io/weellydooh/pen/MWKKoqg

```
<div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
  <p>A simple primary alert—check it out!</p>
  <p>A simple primary alert—check it out!</p>
  <p>A simple primary alert—check it out!</p>
</div>
```

How to set or get rid of margin in an alert box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing . before class selector so it should be

```
.alert p{
  padding:0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Edit: the above will get rid of margin and padding for `<p>` elements that are in the div with class `alert`

So to get rid of margin and padding for div itself use

```
.alert{
  padding:0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Hope it helps